# Packet sniffer get all raw data when I config my Azure web app into https

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, packet-sniffers

After turning my Azure web app into https with Let's encrypt Authority and my custom domain, I try to check all data packet is encrypted or not by web sniffer extension, then I got all the raw data.

[image]

When I try to log in:
[image]

By web sniffer extension that I added to chrome, I get all the raw data:
[image]

I expect that all the post data are encrypted by the https website, but seem I do something wrong or misunderstand something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to view HTTPS data if you sniff on google.com, or other https websites? Probably the extension you're using is looking at the requests from inside the browser, after decryption was performed

I suggest using a tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see the actual on-the-wire data.

Comment: I use Wireshark to check data packet, all the data encrypted by TLS 1.2. But when I check login in another website like Gmail, bank or Facebook, all the id, the password is encrypted. Do you know the way to encrypt id, password also likes this, my webpage now shows all username and password.